# Javascript Prototype changes not showing in instance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I was just trying to get my head around prototypes by playing around with them a bit, but I'm not sure whether I'm getting this right. In this example, I would have expected the new instance of the prototype to be created with the changes defined outside of the original function:

```
function Peeps (){
    this.x = "old"
};
Peeps.prototype.x = "new";

var peep1 = new Peeps();
peep1.x; //still "old"

delete peep1.x;
peep1.x; //now "new"
```

I know that in the last line, the new prototype value for x "shines through" because I deleted the object's native x (which was "old") so it goes up the prototype chain in search of another x instead.
I guess my question is: why was x "old" in the first place for the object? Does the code not look past the original Peeps prototype function for the new object even though one of the prototype's properties got changed before, but when it can't find a native x in the object, it looks beyond the original Peeps function?

I have read through other topics on here, but I don't think I quite understand the reasoning yet. If someone could explain it in their own words, that would be great.

Comment: `this.x` in the constructor creates an own property to instances. `this` in a constructor refers to the newly created object, not constructor's prototype (when called with `new` operator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why was x "old" in the first place for the object? Does the code not look past the original Peeps prototype function for the new object even though one of the prototype's properties got changed before, but when it can't find a native x in the object, it looks beyond the original Peeps function?

Right. Prototypes are meant to provide similar functionality to what inheritance gives us in other languages. You can use `.prototype` to say "most `Peeps`s behave this way". But since your "constructor" function (called via `new Peeps()`) sets a property in this specific instance, that will take precedence over the prototype.

> I have read through other topics on here, but I don't think I quite understand the reasoning yet. If someone could explain it in their own words, that would be great.

Following is an excerpt from [an article I wrote](http://j2jensen.blogspot.com/2014/11/ten-things-javascriptmd.html), which may help:

JavaScript uses a special `prototype` property to solve the problems that other languages use classes to solve. Consider the following:

```
function Person(first, last)
{
    this.first = first;
    this.last = last;
}
var john = new Person("John", "Doe");
var mary = new Person("Mary", "Deer");
Person.prototype.full = function() {return this.first + " " + this.last;};
alert(john.full());
```

There are a lot of things happening here.

1. We create a `function`, which will set properties on its `this` object when called.
2. We create two separate instances of that function by putting the `new` keyword before our function calls. This ensures that `john` and `mary` refer to completely separate objects, each with their own `first` and `last` properties.
3. We create a new function and assign it to the `full` property on our `Person` function's `prototype` property. The `prototype` property exists on all functions, and allows you to define fall-back properties that should exist on every object created from that function.
4. We call the `full()` function on `john`. JavaScript sees that the `john` object doesn't actually have a `full` function on it, so it looks for a `Person.prototype.full()` function and calls that instead. Within that call, however, `this` still refers to the `john` object.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! That made it clearer to me.

Answer (score 0):

An object will check itself before going up the prototype chain. You've set a property on that one object, it will check the existence for it. If it's not there, it'll start going up the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 things here:

Peeps.x (defined inside the function Peeps)
Peeps.prototype.x (defined outside)

Maybe THERE lies the answer: when you remove "x" from Peeps, it takes the existing prototype that acts as a template for x. That's the reason you get those values.